# Ionic Httpclient post request with Content-Type text/xml?

Tags: xml, typescript, post, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am writing a post method with content type `text/xml` where i need to pass XML as data and need to set 3 headers data. Before this i have written api for json datatype and it worked perfectly.

Here is my code

```
let xml = '<Envelope>' +
         '<Body>' +
         '</Body>' +
         '</Envelope>';

const headers= new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
          .set('action','url')
          .set('Authorization', 'auth');

this.httpClient.post(Url, xml, {
          headers: headers,
        })
          .subscribe(result => {
              resolve(result);
            },
            error2 => {
              reject(error2);
            })
```

I have been working on this since 3 days but no luck yet.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to add `Accept` propertie in your header like that : 
 `.set('Accept','text/xml')`

Comment: @Nomade thanks for response but no luck getting 'Http failure response for (unknown url)' in error message

Comment: that is normal, you try to apply anction that named `url`, the action is not clear in your case.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you

Comment: Can you add the full message error ? You have to be sure about your `Url` variable.

Comment: `Error : {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}`. When i hit from postman it work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164571/discussion-between-nomade-and-akshay-deshmukh).